Firebase Auth Redirect when app is not hosted on Firebase
Our React webapp is hosted on AWS (on app.company.com).
We need to add User Management, and currently test Firebase Auth and Cognito.
Since we target mobile devices, the signInWithRedirect() method requires special solutions, like hosting the app on Firebase Hosting.
We are wondering if we can split up the SignUp/SignIn logic from our main app into a dedicated FE app and host only that part on Firebase Hosting (on auth.company.com), but still get the current user's info in our main app (i.e. obtain and use the access token in there).

Reading around points it can be done in some ways, with the need to issue session cookies on our server side, but we don't want to create such sessions.
Trying the reverse proxy setting seems to work (on local dev machines), but we like the idea of splitting the apps (the auth app will hardly ever change).

Would love to hear from someone who experienced the same.
